# cardView with textView disables swiping between tabs

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a cardView / recylerView within a tabbed layout. When attempting to swipe between tabs nothing happens but if I remove the textView I can now swipe again.

How can I send touch events to the card to bypass the textView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bills_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/bills_card"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bills_layout_select"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="3.5"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/billsName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Click"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/billsAmount"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="To Add"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/material_deep_teal_200"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nextBillsDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:text="Bills"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bill_selected_overlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorSelection"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bill_due_overlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorClear"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed the textViews and replaced with the grantland.widget.AutofitTextView and everything works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bills_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/bills_card"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bills_layout_select"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp">

            <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/billsName"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:textColor="@color/material_deep_teal_200"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/billsAmount"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/nextBillsDate"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bill_selected_overlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorSelection"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bill_due_overlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorClear"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```